# Remove edge loop from selection in 2.8

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

What is the best way to remove a whole edge loop from an edge selection in Blender 2.8?

[image]

The Process is as follows:
a) in edit mode, select three (or more) Edge Loops with double click shift + LMB
b) with three edge loops selected, remove loop "A" from selection without losing the selection of "B".

How can this be achieved? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select loops by double-clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+LMB in default Blender's 2.80 keymap. The hotkey for selecting edge loops in 2.80 is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB by default. If you wish to add to the selection or subtract from it something that is already selected you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB.

So the answer to your question is:

When you select a few loops with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB click, you can deselect them the same way clicking LMB while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> on a loop that is already selected.

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin, thank for your answer, but this one does not work if you activate "Emulate 3 Button Mouse in the Preferences. If 3D Button Mouse is disabled, you are right. If it is active, you can choose edge loops with double click, but not de-select certain edge Loops. I'm using Blender Version 2019-04-17 19:26, Hash: b46245470f79.

Comment: That's a bug. You should report it through Help -> Report a Bug. It is understandable they forgot to check this. If you asked me, I would say just do yourself a favor and buy a 3 button mouse. You can get one that works fine for less than 4 euros.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. If its a bug, your answer solves the issuse.

Answer (score -1):

Use edge select. Delete the faces or merge faces[image]